# How to dismiss UICollectionViewController from button in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, dismiss

I am making an onboarding screen, on the last screen I have a button that says "continue" and is supposed to dismiss the onboarding screen. The onboarding screen is a collection view controller with cells as each page. Please do not hesitate to ask for clarification I am don't know what else to add.

Thanks,

**Edit**
So I implemented user Francesco Deliro's answer, first problem was that I accidentally added the "delegate = self" into the viewDidLoad(). I fixed that but still the viewController does not dismiss.
My code is as follow in my viewController cell for item:

```
    let loginCell = LoginCell()
    loginCell.delegate = self
```

Here is the extension

```
extension TutorialViewController: LoginCellDelegate {
func didCompleteOnboarding() {
    print("I should dimiss")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Do I not need to call that function anywhere in the class just leave it outside the main class.

**Edit 2**
Here is how I connected my button action to the originial

```
    @objc func continueTapped() {
    ...
    continueButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.continueButton.transform = .identity
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type = CATransitionType.push
        transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        self?.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        self?.delegate?.didCompleteOnboarding()
    }, completion: { (success) in
        token = true
        defaults.set(token, forKey: "DidSee")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use delegation, for example:

```
protocol YourCellDelegate: class {
    func didCompleteOnboarding()
}
```

Then in your cell:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: YourCellDelegate?

      // in your button action
    func dismissAction() {
        delegate.didCompleteOnboarding()
    }

 }
```

Finally in your view controller set the cell delegate in the cellForItem function:

```
yourCell.delegate = self
```

And add:

```
extension YourViewController: YourCellDelegate {
    func didCompleteOnboarding() {
        // dismiss here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Works but the button isn’t working :( The button doesn’t press

Comment: I need some more information to help you :/ You can ask a new question explaining what happens and showing some of your code.

Comment: I solved it I had to make the button a lazy var -.- But I do have a question about your solution. Where do I call the method didCompleteOnBoarding() in the viewController

Comment: I have implemented everything as you said, however, I don't know what to do from there it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works. When you press the button the delegate call the function, and your view controller receive the callback, there you can implement the dismiss. Update your question and show me how are you implementing it in your code. ;)

Comment: Hey there I updated my answer can you please check my code. And honesly thanks for your time :)

Comment: No that’s the thing the print statement doesn’t show in the log :( That’s why I am confused)

Comment: I updated it this is the selector that occurs when the button is pressed

Comment: Can you link me your project or send me a link to continue the conversation on chat, I’m on mobile now :)

Comment: Here is a google drive link you can use I GitHub takes too much time, thanks again for your time: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BBx1zXESUt9z-hsDl9oEjyvp1wfMSvMu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are welcome, I will check it right now ;) and I will come back to you.

Comment: Got it ;) In few minutes I will send you a link with your project updated and a comment that explains the issue.

Comment: @DadonEl-Kadi Here is the google drive link, I have added a README with the issue explanation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dM6egz4bQq-37NRLuRjUc4jJhu6Eprth/view?usp=sharing 
Let me Know ;)

Comment: Hey Francesco I can't thank you enough, but thanks :) I upvoted btw I don't know who would do that

Comment: Thanks man, also my code is not that messy but I had to move the code from my project to a new due to privacy and stuff. But again thank you :)

Comment: Yeah I thought so ;) You are welcome! Happy to help!